# How to send textfield value to tableview in another viewcontroller

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have situation where i need to send textfield value on a button click in 1 st viewcontroller to 2 nd view controller and display in tableview ,but nothing is displayed in 2 nd view controller with dis code

```
viewcontroller.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfiled;

@end

viewcontroller.m


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   NextViewController*nxt=segue.destinationViewController;      
   nxt.sr=_textfiled.text;

   }

NextviewController.h

@interface NextViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray*arr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString*sr;

Nextviewcontroller.m

@interface NextViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource>

//@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray*finalarr;
@end

@implementation NextViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [_arr addObject:_sr];
  [_table reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return _arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            UITableViewCell*cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
            cell.textLabel.text=[_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints to stop the process at each important step (prepare for segue, viewdidload, cellforrow).
And look at where your string is set, and where it's read. You'll find *easily* where the data is missing, and you'll be able to investigate. this is a very very simple issue, you shouldnt' need to ask on stackoverflow for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nsuserdefaults for passing like cookie or session in web

Comment: i am new to ios development. can u be more specific?is der any way to do using prepareforsegue method

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults for this, it's very very bad practice.
For your information, NSUserDefaults is a persistent storage of keys and values, that you usually use for stuff like... remembering user name, or some permanent settings. You don't use that to pass data, ever.

Comment: @Nishanth not bad for JUST practice if you dont want use nsuserdefault you can call void used parameter from second controller to pass in first controller

Answer (score 0):

```
//The below should not be used in prepare segue.use in any button action.

if(!secondVC) {
 secondVC = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                 bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVCIdetifier"];
}
 secondVC.tempString = tf.text;
[self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NextViewController*nxt=segue.destinationViewController;
     NSLog(@"%@",_textfiled);     
     nxt.sr=_textfiled.text;

 }

Comment: i have written this in preparefrsegue but it what should be written in viewdidload of 2nd view controller

Comment: first you are able to see the text in tempString ? you want put that string in tableview cell  ? if yes then write [tableView reloadData] in NextViewController viewdidload method;

Comment: are u still facing problem ?

Comment: check here     [_arr addObject:_sr];  sr contains data or not

Comment: Boss first allocate it like _arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]

Comment: ya....did that in preparefor segue method when i come back  to 1 st view controller and submit new value it shows only current value in 2 nd viewcontroller.previous value is lost......so where should be the best idea to allocate _arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]

Comment: Boss first you should be strong in oops. like if you user a segue from one VC to other a new copy of ViewController is created. So that every time you will get a new value . you never get a previouse value. For such things you have to use Delegate design pattern or see the code some thing like i update.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `[_arr addObject:_sr];` first. See if the _sr value is empty or not. If yes, your problem is before, if not, your problem is after.

From there on out you'll be able to pinpoint the exact problem. From the quick read I'd say you either don't get the string data at all, or you're not using a segue and therefore prepareforsegue isn't called.

Learn to use breakpoints. If you dont' know how, look it up, it's incredibly easy and it's 70% of your job.

With that advice alone you'll be able to fix your problem, and many more to come.